# Check if word can be made out of given letters fast

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I have some letters and frequency counts. And I have a very long list of words (1M say).

Suppose I have `A-1, B-1, D-1` ("at most one `A`, at most one `B`, at most one `D`"), then I can make `"BAD"`, but not `"RAD"`

Can I know in which words can be made out of those letters, in *logarithmic* time, or something like that, instead of iterating through all words and looking at the counts of each letter in the word?

What data structure can be used for these words? A trie maybe? I'm unaware of them. It would also be great if I can store letters required for each word with it. Please help!

Comment: Logarithmic with respect to what? You will have to examine every single word, so obviously you won't find any algorithm that's sublinear in the number of words.

Comment: @ruakh It depends. If you have to set the list of words only once but will attempt many times against it, you can make the lookup a lot faster by doing preprocessing.

Comment: Worst-case, though, I give you 100 of each letter and ask you to find all words which can be made from those. You must produce every word in that case.

Comment: @Patashu Yeah, I meant doing some preprocessing. And I have to query many times against those stored words.

Comment: @nneonneo No, that's not what I asked, I have the words already.

Comment: @Bruce: I was trying to say that you have to produce all 1M words in your list. (Sorry I wasn't clear). It's a worst-case scenario, but it illustrates that no algorithm can do better than linear in the worst case.

Comment: This seems like a very good problem to post on [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nneonneo I don't have to produce those words! I'm given those words, and some alphabets with their counts, and I gotta determine which of those words could be made out of the given alphabets in O(log(number of words)) time or similar

Comment: You have a list of 1000000 words. I give you a bag of letters containing 100 of each letter in the alphabet. You can make every single word in your list with that bag of letters. Consequently, your algorithm **must** output every single word in that list. You cannot have an algorithm which runs in O(log n) time but produces O(n) output.

Comment: @nneonneo Oh, that's what you meant..

Comment: @EAKAE: No, not really. Code golfers will give you a small program, but not necessarily a fast program.

Comment: @nneonneo You can chose what type of challenge it is, shortest code, or fastest code, or whatever rubric you want, as long as it is clearly defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (literal) sketch of a data structure.

```
             [root]
         ----- | -----
       A1      A2     B1 ...
  ----/-    ---|---    -\----
 B1 C1 [a]  B1 B2 C1  C1 C2 D2 ...
```

It's a tree, where the leaf nodes are the words in the word list. The words at a leaf node are composed exactly of the bag of letters consisting of the path from the root to that node. Non-leaf nodes are labelled with a letter and a count. A child of a node must either be a leaf (a word) or have a letter strictly later in the alphabet. So, to get to "cat", you go down the path `A1,C1,T1`, and `cat` (and `act`) will be a child of T1. At each node, you traverse the children which have count ≤ your input count (so for the bag `A3, C1, T2`, you would traverse any node labelled A1,A2,A3, C1, T1 or T2).

The traversal takes O(n) time in the worst case (every word matches), but on average takes substantially less. For a small input bag, it will only traverse a few nodes. For a large input bag, it traverses many nodes, but it will also find many words.

The tree contains *at most* one node per letter in the wordlist, so it will have size at most proportional to the length of the wordlist.

This is a time- and space- efficient structure which can be computed and stored relatively easily -- it won't take much more space than your wordlist, and queries pretty fast.

Comment: It's a good solution for where you have just the right number of letters (as is mine) but falls down since you have to store `cat` at _many_ different locations (since it can be built out of anything from `act` to `aaaaaccccccccccttttxyzzy`). That was the space cost i alluded to in my comment.

Comment: No, you only store it at one location: as a child of A1-C1-T1 (which in the uncompressed version is `A1-B0-C1-D0-...-S0-T1`). If you are given `aaaaacccccccccctxyzzy` as input, you will traverse `A1-C1-T1` as part of the algorithm (as well as `A1-C2-T1` "acct", `X1-Y2-Z2` "xyzzy", etc.). (The notation here assumes the zero-compression is being used, i.e. that `X1` is a direct child of the root).

Comment: Okay, then it's not as efficient as you make out. Yes, it depends on the number of characters in the wordlist but, in order to find the words, you have to traverse said tree once for every combination of letters. Eg, `act` would require traversal for `a`, `c`, `t`, `ac`, `ca`, `at`, `ta`, `ct`, `tc` and the six different combos of `act`. That's going to get unweildy for large bag sizes.

Comment: Not saying mine is better since it suffers from the same shortcoming :-)

Comment: Nope. You always traverse in alphabetical order. So, at A1, you examine C1 and T1. At A1-C1, you traverse T1 and get "CAT". At A1-T1, you get "AT". You go back to the root and traverse C1, then C1-T1. Then you go back to the root and examine T1.

Comment: Have to respectfully disagree there, order is largely irrelevant. That's because `cat` is an outcome of much more than even the sorted "a1c1t1" node. It's also part of `a1c1t1u3v5w8x2y5z9` node :-) In other words, given actuuuvvvvvwwwwwwwwxxyyyyyzzzzzzzzz`, cat is a possible outcome (as is act by the way, so you'll need multiple words at each node if you're ignoring the order).

Comment: You stop at A1-C1-T1 and find CAT. CAT is not a child of A1-C1-T1-U3-V5, because that doesn't spell CAT. (And, if that doesn't spell anything at all, that node doesn't exist.)

Comment: See first comment to my answer: "Yes, words that use only _some_ of the letters are possible" (my italics).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24256/discussion-between-nneonneo-and-paxdiablo)

Answer (score 1):

If you need words that have *all* the letters, I've done something like that before (my crossword cheat program, I'm ashamed to say).

I took a dictionary file and preprocessed it so each line had the letters sorted, followed by the word itself, like:

```
aaadkrrv:aardvark
```

Then, if you have the letters `ardvkraa`, sort that, then look for the lines containing that string before the colon. I used `grep` since O(n) was good enough but you could easily put all the lines into a balanced binary tree to give you O(log n) complexity.

That won't help much if you're after words that use only *some* of the letters but it's not clear whether that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, words that use only some of the letters are possible.

Comment: In Python, `d = {''.join(sorted(w)):w for w in wordlist}; print d[''.join(sorted(s))]` will do it in O(n) preprocess time and O(1) lookup time, no binary tree required. (But this doesn't solve OP's problem).

Comment: @Bruce, then I think you're probably limited to O(n). It's always _possible_ to trade space for time but I suspect the space cost here will be too much to pay.

Comment: @nneonneo, that depends on what you're using for n. Anything with a sort in it is unlikely to be O(n) without some sleight of hand :-)

Comment: OK, O(n log k) where k is the average length of a word and n is the length of the input (not the number of words). But, k is very small relative to n.

Comment: @paxdiablo I do have a lot of space. Can you suggest a tradeoff solution?

Comment: @Bruce: the structure I proposed is space-efficient but (I claim) optimal for query time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I can grasp the problem you present 100% from your description, but from what I see, you can do the following:

You index your list of words. For example, 'B1' is one index, which will contain a list of entries which contain not more than one letter B, or otherwise fulfill the requirement of the problem you are solving. You can also have "composite" indices, like 'A1B1' along the same lines. Given the budget of time you can afford for indexing, you can create pretty deep hashes. If you are using an alphabet with 26 letters and want to hash 4-letter combinations, it's only 14,950 indexes, and if it's 3 letters, it's a meager 2,600. Indices can be built during one iteration over the list, so their creation is linear. Once you are past this stage, a large part of your lookups will be logarithmic. In my example, your 4 letter word lookup will be a single fetch. Of course, for longer letter combinations you use the index first, then iterate.